# Custom Timer Job not running on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

All of the custom timer jobs are not running without showing any error/correlation IDs. Below is the only stack I could see from ULS logs even after enabling verbose - no error/failures/exceptions are captured.

```
03-03-2018 11:42:16.51   w3wp.exe (0x5E18)    0x466C SharePoint Foundation Topology 8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject CicoCaseSummaryJob Name=Amlak CICO Report Job. Version: 6456266 Ensure: False, HashCode: 43137058, Id: d7b3b6f4-9c43-4b98-91dd-740b41fec886, Stack: 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.Update()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.JobEditPage.BtnEnableJob_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     
at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     
at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)       c8cf4f9e-bdbe-c043-f022-28a78278cbdc.
03-03-2018 11:42:16.51          w3wp.exe (0x5E18)    0x466C           SharePoint Foundation           Topology            88b9    Verbose           Determining if the current user is a SharePoint Farm Administrator c8cf4f9e-bdbe-c043-f022-28a78278cbdc
03-03-2018 11:42:16.52          NodeRunnerContent1-02bf3c7c-ee2 (0x0BCC)        0x4818            Search            Logging Correlation Data       77a3    Verbose           Ending correlation.     af960167-f03c-41fb-8866-559bb2adb1a1
```

We have already tried below:

1. Cleared configuration cache.
2. Redeployed the timer job.
3. Restarted services and even the server.

Note: Default timer jobs are running fine without any issue.

Comment: could you please try to run them manual and see if it works? also check the status of the solution you deployed? also check the SharePoint admin service is running?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem description:**

In your SharePoint farm you start to experience that the timer jobs are not running normally. Like custom timer jobs or one-time timer jobs do not run once you try running it. Another good example to identify the problem is to run "Merge-SPLogFile" command that creates one-time timer jobs to collect logs from all the servers in the farm.

**Cause:**

Although the SharePoint Timer service was started in services.msc, the timer service instance object (this is a SharePoint farm object) may be set to “Disabled”.Use below script to get the status of all the timer instances in the farm.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instance
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
```

**Solution 1:**
Run below PowerShell command to re-provision the instance to "Online" state.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
$disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne "Online"}
if ($disabledTimers -ne $null)
{
foreach ($timer in $disabledTimers)
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Timer service instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is NOT Online. Current status:" $timer.Status
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Attempting to set the status of the service instance to online..."
$timer.Provision()
$timer.Start()
write-host -ForegroundColor Red "You MUST now go restart the SharePoint timer service on server " $FT.Server.Name}}
else
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All Timer Service Instances in the farm are online. No problems found!"
}
```

**Solution 2 (only for SharePoint 2016 MinRole setups):**

Start the Instance via Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Services on Server -> Change the view in the upper right corner to "Any" -> Locate "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer" and klick "Fix".

**Reference:** [SharePoint Timer jobs not running(Specially one-time timer jobs)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sujesh/2017/10/16/sharepoint-timer-jobs-not-runningspecially-one-time-timer-jobs/)