# SharePoint jobs haven't run after a specific date!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, timer-service

When I check the job history on SharePoint 2016 central administration, I see all job's last successful runs are about one week ago! SharePoint timer service is running and no related error has been found in logs. I noticed the problem when I was checking the reason for not publishing the new content types on the other sites and nothing happens when I run the content type subscriber job manually. 
I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, open SharePoint Management Shell and execute code below:

```
# Get WFE server on which you want to restore the timer service
$server = Get-SPServer -Identity "<name of WFE server>" 
$ts = $server.ServiceInstances | ? { $_.GetType().Name -like "*sptimerservice*" } | Select -First 1
$ts.AllowContentDatabaseJobs = $true
$ts.AllowServiceJobs = $true
$ts.Update()
```

Restart SharePoint Timer Service.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7de54ba4-9ca5-428d-acc2-24a696d751d8/sharepoint-timer-jobs-not-running-appearing-as-not-applicable-in-log?forum=sharepointadmin

[Custom Timer Job not running on SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237434/custom-timer-job-not-running-on-sharepoint-2013)